# Year in bibliography with brackets

Tags: bibtex, natbib

i want in my bibliography the year within brackets.
How can I customize my style?

I think I have to change the `FUNCTION {format.date}`, but how?

regards

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,german]{book}
\usepackage[german,ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}
\cite{Alonso.2004}
\bibliography{Literatur}
\end{document}
```

```
@book{Alonso.2004,
 author = {Alonso, Gustavo and Casati, Fabio and Kuno, Harumi and Machiraju, Vijay},
 year = {2004},
 title = {Web services: Concepts, architectures and applications},
 url = {http://www.loc.gov/catdir/enhancements/fy0817/2004298168-d.html},
 address = {Berlin},
 publisher = {Springer},
 isbn = {3540440089},
 series = {Data-centric systems and applications}
}
```

Now my bibliography looks like this:

> G. Alonso, F. Casati, H. Kuno, and V. Machiraju. 2004, Web services:
>   Concepts, architectures and applications. Data-centric systems and
>   applications. Springer, Berlin, 2004.

But I want it looks like this:

> G. Alonso, F. Casati, H. Kuno, and V. Machiraju. (2004), Web services:
>   Concepts, architectures and applications. Data-centric systems and
>   applications. Springer, Berlin, 2004.

The First Year within brackets

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide your bibliography style, but it should work like this: add the two lines to `format.date` as

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  month empty$
    'skip$
    { month
      " " * swap$ *
    }
  if$
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ %% added
  { "(" swap$ * ")" *}     %% added
  if$
  extra.label *
}
```

To have a period in front of the year instead of the comma, issue a `new.block` command before the output of the year, like I did here for the `article` type

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      eid empty$
        { format.vol.num.pages output }
        { format.vol.num.eid output }
      if$
      new.block                        %% added
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      eid empty$
        { format.pages output }
        { format.eid output }
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.issn output
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Comment: I do not provide my bibliography style because it was standard style. It works, Thank you a Lot. But there is still a Problem. The second Year shall not within brackets, but with your solution it is :( This second year should belongs to the address field. Maybe I have to change another Function for this?

Comment: @Igor Your style `myplainnat` is *not* standard, `plainnat` is. I used `plainnat` as a start, and added the *two* lines to `format.date`. If you need two different forms of `format.date`, you have to define two, and then use them in the right place. The first would be the unaltered form, the second the new form. But ultimately, you should provide your `myplainnat.bst`, so maybe a better solution can be found.

Comment: Oh thats a good suggestion. I will try this. unfortunately i can not provide my style, because it have to much characters :(

Comment: Now I have a separate Function for years with brackets. The Function for formate.date is standard.
So it works as expected

Comment: Maybe you can give me a hint to merge the adress with the year like "Berlin 2004" and not "Berlin, 2004"? I added just an additional "year"-line after the address at the Function{book}...

Comment: @Igor That is a bit tricky. `plainnat` channels all output through `output.nonnull`, and there it is decided what punctuation to be used depending on the `output.state`. So if you squeeze `before.all 'output.state :=` between `address output` and `year output`, `plainnat` should not write a comma (not tested).

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. Your Hint is almost working. Now I have instead of "Berlin, 2011" "Berlin2011". So it needs a space somewhere?

Comment: For the solution look at my answer.... Thanks a lot, you made my day :-))

Answer (score 0):

Fix the address year problem with another customized formate.date Function

```
  FUNCTION {format.dateWithSpace}
    { year duplicate$ empty$
        { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
           pop$ "" }
        'skip$
      if$
      month empty$
        'skip$
        { month
          " " * swap$ *
        }
      if$                                   
      duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$              %% added
      { " " swap$ * "" *}                   %% added
      if$
      extra.label *
    }
```