# Extra.label within brackets after year in Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, brackets

This is a follow up question to [Year in bibliography with brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98880/year-in-bibliography-with-brackets/515210#515210), where I also took this MWE from.

```latex
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,12pt,german]{book}
\usepackage[german,ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}
\cite{lastname.2019a}
\cite{lastname.2019b}
\bibliography{Literatur}
\end{document}
```

```
@book{lastname.2019a,
 author = {Firstname Lastname},
 year = {2019},
 title = {Title 1},
 address = {Berlin},
 publisher = {Springer}
}

@book{lastname.2019b,
 author = {Firstname Lastname},
 year = {2019},
 title = {Title 2},
 address = {Berlin},
 publisher = {Springer}
}
```

I edited my .bst file as the code provided in the answers like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  month empty$
    'skip$
    { month
      " " * swap$ *
    }
  if$
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ %% added
  { "(" swap$ * ")" *}     %% added
  if$
  extra.label *
}
```

However, my Bibliography now looks like this:

> Lastname, Firstname. (2019)a, Title 1. Springer, Berlin.
>
> Lastname, Firstname. (2019)b, Title 2. Springer, Berlin.

But I want it to look like this:

> Lastname, Firstname. (2019a), Title 1. Springer, Berlin.
>
> Lastname, Firstname. (2019b), Title 2. Springer, Berlin.

I know I have to edit the `extra.label` line in my `.bst` file somehow, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99987/35864 help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to simply move the line `extra.label *` before the new added lines.

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
  month empty$
    'skip$
    { month
      " " * swap$ *
    }
  if$
  extra.label *
  duplicate$ empty$
    'skip$
    { "(" swap$ * ")" * }
  if$
}
```

The complete file can be downloaded at https://gist.github.com/moewew/0b5992f6973bbc6af7d3c2cd5f0e297c (including an exact diff to `plainnat.bst`). It results in

[image: Firstname Lastname. Title 1. Springer, Berlin, (2019a).//Firstname Lastname. Title 1. Springer, Berlin, (2019b).]

when used in the MWE from the question.